# Show a SnackBar in a dynamic Scaffold fails

Tags: flutter

I have a Home widget with a build method that returns either a Scaffold or a loader widget, based on a boolean.
The boolean is set to false, so I return the Scaffold first. I then have a button inside that Scaffold (inside a builder so it will get the Scaffold context for the SnackBar) which changes the bool to true (and as a result returns the loader widget) and after evaluating an input, sets the bool back to false, causing the Scaffold to be returned.

Within that onPressed() function I also have a SnackBar which I would like to show, but fails with the following error message:

```
Looking up a deactivated widget's ancestor is unsafe. At this point the state of the widget's element tree is no longer stable. To safely refer to a widget's ancestor in its dispose() method, save a reference to the ancestor by calling dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType() in the widget's didChangeDependencies() method.
```

(I guess that when I'm returning the loader widget and then returning the Scaffold, something got messed up with the context, I assume the Scaffold returned is a new one, but I am not sure)

The entire Widget class:

```
class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  bool loading = false;
  final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return loading
        ? Loading()
        : Scaffold(
            key: _scaffoldKey,
            // backgroundColor: Colors.deepPurple[100],
            appBar: AppBar(
              title: Text(
                'netlush.co.il/home',
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w100,
                  fontSize: 16.0,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            body: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 16.0),
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Builder(
                    builder: (context) => RaisedButton(
                      onPressed: () async {
                        setState(() => loading = true);
                        List<UserModel> users = await Api().getCustomers();
                        users = null;
                        if (users == null) {
                          setState(() {
                            loading = false;
                            print('users list is empty');
                            Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
                              content: Text('Context from Builder'),
                              duration: Duration(seconds: 3),
                            ));
                          });
                        } else {
                          setState(() => loading = false);
                          // navigate to users page
                          Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/users',
                              arguments: {'users': users});
                        }
                      },
                      child: Text('Clients*'),
                    ),
                  ),
                  RaisedButton(
                    onPressed: () {},
                    child: Text('Payments'),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          );
  }
}
```

*the user=null statement is there for debugging purposes.

Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can copy paste run full code below 
You can use `addPostFrameCallback`
code snippet

```
WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
                            _scaffoldKey.currentState.showSnackBar(SnackBar(
                              content: Text('Context from Builder'),
                              duration: Duration(seconds: 3),
                            ));
                          });
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  bool loading = false;
  final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return loading
        ? Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator())
        : Scaffold(
            key: _scaffoldKey,
            // backgroundColor: Colors.deepPurple[100],
            appBar: AppBar(
              title: Text(
                'netlush.co.il/home',
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w100,
                  fontSize: 16.0,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            body: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 16.0),
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Builder(
                    builder: (context) => RaisedButton(
                      onPressed: () async {
                        setState(() => loading = true);
                        //List<UserModel> users = await Api().getCustomers();
                        await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 3), () {});

                        var users;
                        users = null;
                        if (users == null) {
                          setState(() {
                            loading = false;
                            print('users list is empty');
                          });

                          WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
                            _scaffoldKey.currentState.showSnackBar(SnackBar(
                              content: Text('Context from Builder'),
                              duration: Duration(seconds: 3),
                            ));
                          });
                        } else {
                          setState(() => loading = false);
                          // navigate to users page
                          Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/users',
                              arguments: {'users': users});
                        }
                      },
                      child: Text('Clients*'),
                    ),
                  ),
                  RaisedButton(
                    onPressed: () {},
                    child: Text('Payments'),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          );
  }
}

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: Home(),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it is working when I comment out the Api call, but when I do the Api call, the problem still persist. Could you try to call a Future in your code that delay for ±2 seconds? let's see if this is still working at your end. Thanks!

Comment: I have update full code. you need to use _scaffoldKey.currentState in this case.

Comment: Thank you, it solved the problem. I would love to better understand what was the problem and how the code you recommended fixed it, so if you have time to explain (or point me to the relevant documents), that would be great. Thanks again!

Comment: please reference this https://www.didierboelens.com/2019/04/addpostframecallback/